# Now that the Star Wars franchise belongs to Disney, who owns the rights to Star Wars the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, disney, copyright

With much research I have come to a wall. I have am a huge fan of the "Star Wars the Clone Wars" series and I don't doubt there are others who love it as much as I do but what I want to know is who owns the franchise? Yes, Disney may now own the rights to "Star Wars" but that was for the movies NOT the series "Star Wars the Clone Wars." I have looked around the internet a while and have found no evidence of the true owner of the series. I do know that the series was cancelled halfway through season six and was left off there but what I don't know is who chose to do this and what was their reasoning?

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was about as solid as it gets. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 18):

Star Wars: The Clone Wars (and indeed all Star Wars properties) are copyrighted to LucasFilm. As of October 30, 2012, [Disney acquired LucasFilm](https://web.archive.org/web/20121106011213/http://thewaltdisneycompany.com/disney-news/press-releases/2012/10/disney-acquire-lucasfilm-ltd) and all ancillary rights to the various Star Wars films and spin-off TV series **including The Clone Wars film and TV series.**

> Under the deal, Disney will acquire ownership of Lucasfilm, a leader
>   in entertainment, innovation and technology, **including its massively
>   popular and "evergreen" Star Wars franchise** and its operating
>   businesses in live action film production, consumer products,
>   animation, visual effects, and audio post production. Disney will also
>   acquire the substantial portfolio of cutting-edge entertainment
>   technologies that have kept audiences enthralled for many years.
>   Lucasfilm, headquartered in San Francisco, operates under the names
>   Lucasfilm Ltd., LucasArts, Industrial Light & Magic, and Skywalker
>   Sound, and the present intent is for Lucasfilm employees to remain in
>   their current locations.

[image]

> **In addition to its motion-picture and television production
>   operations, the company’s global activities include** Industrial Light &
>   Magic and Skywalker Sound, serving the digital needs of the
>   entertainment industry for visual-effects and audio post-production;
>   LucasArts, a leading developer and publisher of interactive
>   entertainment software worldwide; Lucas Licensing, which manages the
>   global merchandising activities for Lucasfilm’s entertainment
>   properties; **Lucasfilm Animation**; and Lucas Online creates
>   Internet-based content for Lucasfilm’s entertainment properties and
>   businesses. - <sub><sup>[Waltdisney.com](https://thewaltdisneycompany.com/disney-to-acquire-lucasfilm-ltd/)</sup></sub>

[image]

Comment: But did Disney cancel the "Star Wars the Clone Wars" series due to the fact that they released "Star Wars: The Force Awakens"?

Comment: @KryptoKnight - No, they [most likely cancelled it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86646/why-did-disney-cancel-star-wars-the-clone-wars-tv-series) because they wanted the studio to work on a new franchised property; Star Wars: Rebels that would tie in with their merchandising strategy.

Comment: I heard that Netflix had informed Disney that "Star Wars the Clone Wars" was headed down a dark path, what did they mean by that?

Comment: @KryptoKnight - Well, if you look at the "lost" episodes of Clone Wars, Season 6 they're dramatically less upbeat and pleasant than Rebels. It's not unusual for a series that goes on for a while to become progressively more "adult" as their target audience ages but from a Disney POV, a reboot makes lots of sense when focusing on a younger audience.

Comment: Could they possibly continue it except rate it differently?

Comment: @KryptoKnight - I don't see why not, but then I don't see why they'd want to.

Comment: It would bring back the worldwide fans of the series.

Comment: @KryptoKnight - Those fans are old now and happily watching Star Wars: Rebels with their kids.

Comment: I'm not that old.  XD

Comment: @KryptoKnight - In that case, you're probably getting all excited about Star Wars : Rogue One (darker and intended for a slightly older audience) and busily buying box-sets of Clone Wars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37024/discussion-between-kryptoknight-and-richard).